# Problem with getting HTML from email: I only receive a string of characters

Tags: python, html, email, parsing

I need to get html out of my emails, the code I wrote worked fine for other emails but for an email from one sender it returned a large string of characters instead of the HTML.

update: the string I received is in base64, I still have a problem since my code only gets the base64 part of the email but not the HTML.

This is what my code looks like:

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.yahoo.com')
m.login('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx')

rv, mailboxes = m.list()
if rv == 'OK':
    print ("Mailboxes:")
    print (mailboxes)


def process_mailbox(m):
  rv, data = m.search(None, "ALL")
  if rv != 'OK':
      print ("No messages found!")
      return

  for num in data[0].split():
      rv, data = m.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
      if rv != 'OK':
          print ("ERROR getting message"), num
          return

      msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
      print ('Message %s: %s' % (num, msg['Subject']))
      print ('Raw Date:', msg['Date'])
      date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(msg['Date'])
      if date_tuple:
          local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
              email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
          print ("Local Date:"), \
              local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")



m.select('MAILBOX', readonly=True)

resp, items = m.search(None, "ALL")
items = items[0].split() # getting the mails id



for emailid in items:
  resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)") 
  raw_email = data[0][1]
  print (raw_email)
```

Usually I get the raw email at this point, but this time all I got was a large string of characters and never got to the actual HTML:

Content-Length: 9617 X-Antivirus: Avast (VPS 190503-4, 05/03/2019), Inbound message X-Antivirus-Status: Clean PHRhYmxlIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LWZhbWlseTogVGFob21hLCBHZW5ldmEsIHNhbnMtc2Vy aWY7IiB3aWR0aD0iNjMwIiBjZWxsc3BhY2luZz0iMCIgY2VsbHBhZGRpbmc9IjEwIj4g PHRib2R5PgogPHRyPgogPHRkPgogPHRhYmxlIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LWZhbWlseTogVGFo b21hLCBHZW5ldmEsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7IiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgY2VsbHNwYWNpbmc9 IjAiIGNlbGxwYWRkaW5nPSIwIiBib3JkZXI9IjAiPiA8dGJvZHk+CiA8dHI+CiA8dGQg d2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiPjxjZW50ZXI+PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly9zaG9wLm1lcmNvbGEu Y29tIj48aW1nIHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9tZWRpYS5tZXJjb2xhLmNvbS9hc3NldHMvaW1h Z2VzL3Nob3Bsb2dvL01lcmNvbGFfTG9nb3YyLnBuZyIgd2lkdGg9IjMxNCIgaGVpZ2h0 PSIzOSIgYm9yZGVyPSIwIiAvPjwvYT48L2NlbnRlcj48L3RkPgogPC90cj4KIDx0cj4K IDx0ZD4KPGhyIHN0eWxlPSJjb2xvcjogI2VjZWNlYzsgd2lkdGg6IDEwMCU7IiAvPjwv dGQ+CiA8L3RyPgogPC90Ym9keT4KIDwvdGFibGU+CiA8L3RkPgogPC90cj4KIDx0cj4K IDx0ZCBzdHlsZT0icGFkZGluZzogMTBweCAzMHB4IDMwcHggMzBweDsiPjxzcGFuIHN0 eWxlPSJmb250LXNpemU6IDE1cHQ7IGZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OiBib2xkOyBjb2xvcjogIzEy NmFhYTsiPlNoaXBwaW5nIENvbmZpcm1hdGlvbjwvc3Bhbj48YnIgLz48YnIgLz48Yj48 c3BhbiBzdHlsZT0iZm9udC1zaXplOiAxMnB0OyI+RGVhciBQYXRyaWNpYSBTY2hsZXVz bmVyLDwvc3Bhbj48L2I+PGJyIC8+PGJyIC8+PHNwYW4gc3R5bGU9ImZvbnQtc2l6ZTog MTJwdDsiPlRoYW5rIHlvdSBmb3IgeW91ciByZWNlbnQgb3JkZXIgZnJvbSA8YSBocmVm PSJodHRwczovL3Nob3AubWVyY29sYS5jb20iPk1lcmNvbGE8L2E+LiBXZSBhcmUgcGxl YXNlZCB0byBpbmZvcm0geW91IHRoYXQgeW91IGFyZSBub3cgb25lIHN0ZXAgY2xvc2Vy IHRvIHRha2luZyBjb250cm9sIG9mIHlvdXIgaGVhbHRoISBZb3VyIG9yZGVyIG51bWJl ciBPMTUwOTMxMDkgaGFzIGJlZW4gc2hpcHBlZCBhbmQgaXMgb24gaXRzIHdheSB0byB5 b3UuPGJyIC8+PGJyIC8+VGhlIHNoaXBtZW50IGRldGFpbHMgYXJlIGFzIGJlbG93Ojwv c3Bhbj48YnIgLz48YnIgLz4gPHRhYmxlIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXNpemU6IDEycHQ7IGZv bnQtZmFtaWx5OiBUYWhvbWEsIEdlbmV2YSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZjsgdGV4dC1hbGlnbjog bGVmdDsiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBjZWxsc3BhY2luZz0iMCIgY2VsbHBhZGRpbmc9Ijci

Comment: Looks like base64 encoded. You have to decode it.

Comment: Looks like you're right, iti s base64. Now there's a second problem where I only get that part of the email and not the rest of the email with html code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are able to create a Message object from the raw data, you can use its capabilities to extract the information that you require.

```
from email import policy

# Set the policy to create an EmailMessage instance. 
msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1], policy=policy.default)
# Get the part most likely to be the preferred body.
body = msg.get_body()
# get_content() will automatically decode from base64 or quoted-printable. 
print(body.get_content())
```

Setting the policy to `policy.default` when creating the message object ensures that an `EmailMessage` instance is returned - this object provides the `get_body` and `get_content` methods.

[EmailMessage.get_body()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_body) will

> Return the MIME part that is the best candidate to be the “body” of the message.

You can provide a list of subtypes to guide its behaviour.